# Input Checkbox Array, if unchecked no value is sent by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a form which is dynamically created so I have an input array!

### Solved: `<input type="hidden" name="smoker_patient[ID]" value="off" />` hidden field for every checkbox with the same ID!#

The rows look like:

```
<tr><td>
  [stuff]
   <input type="checkbox" name="smoker_patient[1]" class="smoker" id="cbx1" checked="checked"/>
  [stuff]
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
  [stuff]
    <input type="checkbox" name="smoker_patient[2]" class="smoker" id="cbx2"/>
  [stuff]
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
  [stuff]
    <input type="checkbox" name="smoker_patient[3]" class="smoker" id="cbx3" checked="checked"/>
  [stuff]
</td></tr>
```

As you can see, cbx1 and cbx3 are checked.(only to show the error) But the array which is sent by jQuery only consists of

```
smoker_patient[0] = 'on'
smoker_patient[1] = 'on'
```

but it should be...

```
smoker_patient[0] = 'on'
smoker_patient[1] = 'off'
smoker_patient[2] = 'on'
```

So i get the error in PHP:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in newcoexposition.php on line XX

Comment: That is *expected* behavior - checkboxes are never posted if they're not checked.

Comment: So what can i do now? I need this because the entire form is bigger and there are 3 tables which are dynamic!

Comment: I don't even totally know what's going on here but editing the answer into the question and adding \*\*[SOLVED]\*\* to the title is not how things are done around here.

Comment: If you want to guarantee that a value is posted for yes or no, you'd be much better off  just using a pair of radio buttons representing y/n rather than trying to hack around the normal expected behavior for a checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure of your syntax in the naming of your input sections. You seem to know what your doing well enough that I don't think you are unaware that if you `name=""` them all the same then your `$_POST` or `$_GET` of that input will only see the same one over and over. I am sure you have thought of this and the `name="smoker_patient[]"` must be just a pseudo place holder.

That being said, if that's not the problem with the code then you can approach it like this.

You need to use PHP to make sure that the $_POST value has been set somewhere. When a checkbox is selected or checked and the form is sent via $_POST for example, the information isn't sent like other HTML objects. Instead it is sent as either `ON` or `OFF` in your $_POST response handling PHP page.

@mithunsatheesh is correct the only way to do this is to use an `isset($_POST['checkbox'])` to make sure it has been set, or checked...

If your sections are dynamic then you can use php and a simple counter to make sure that all dynamic checkboxes are given unique names and identifiers like so...

I would first see how many boxes I need and then...

```
$totalNumOfBoxes = 3;
for($i=0; $i<$totalNumOfBoxes; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>
              <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="smoker_patient_".$i class="smoker" id="cbx".$i />
              </td>
          </tr>';
}
```

Then you would have a series of boxes each with unique identifiers, so that when you submit the form each checkbox can't be confused with its sibling checkbox in the `$_POST` array.

On the other side, in the `$_POST` response handling PHP file you would then look for them all by  giving yourself a `$_GET` variable filled with how many boxes there are since testing the boundaries to see how many have been returned isn't possible with `isset()` and checkboxes ...

I would make a form that has all these boxes have a `method: POST` and `action: myHandlerPHPFile.php?boxCount=3`so when you get to this side of the `POST` request you can make your `$totalNumOfBoxes = $_GET['boxCount']`.

You can set the `action: myHandlerPHPFile.php?boxCount=` count to 3 by using the same look that makes the boxes to also add this counted variable to the mix.